# Install XP (non bootable CD) from within Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, installation, bootable-media, compact-disc

I'm in need of some help. I'm currently running on Windows 7 ultimate x64. I need to intstall a fresh copy of XP on my machine (dual boot) but I have a non bootable CD of XP. Is there any way to install it from Windows 7 itself? 7 doesn't give me an option to install XP as it is an older version of OS. Please assist.

PS: I don't want to use VMware or VirtualBox.

Comment: What do you mean by Non-bootable CD?

Comment: As in, the cd doesn't boot up when i restart the pc. (My boot order has my dvd drive listed first)

Comment: Interesting. Was this an original XP CD, or a downloaded one? (Downloaded does not mean illegal)

Comment: I downloaded it. I'd written it a long time ago and I'd done the mistake of not writing the ISO file directly. I extracted it and manually burnt it. So I don't think it'll boot. And as expected, when I run the setup via windows 7, the install xp option is disabled. Is there any way to override that via command line?

Comment: I'm not sure. My suggestion would be downloading it again and burning without unpacking.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work for you.

I hope you have more than one drive in your PC.
put all windows seven installation file in any drive except where it is currently installed for ex. if your current windows in drive C\ then copy files in drive D or any other drive but not C.
Now click on setup.exe and start installing windows as normal. It worked for me on Vista a long time back but i am not sure about seven so you better be careful.

And there is one more option install it in some different drive like if currently installed in C\ drive than install it in driver D.  After installation format the drive C\ from drive D.

Both solution worked for me on Vista like 2 years back as i did not have the bootable DVD.
But i never tried it on seven. SO think twice and do some R&D on it before using any of these options

Thanks.

Comment: Guess I'll just re download a fresh copy. Thanks

Comment: Sorry bro i tried my level best to help you. But it's OK after all your problem is solved now. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Dosn't Microsoft still provide ISO for XP (if not I am sure you can find one online somewhere and just put your valid key in).

I think the easiet and with the least problems solution is to jut burn a new bootable dvd. Or if your computer can support it, use a USB stick.

Comment: Guess I'll just re download a fresh copy. Thanks